# Is there a way for pdftotext (linux poppler-utils) to take a binary instead of a pdf file?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pdftotext

`pdftotext` looks like it only takes the pdf file name or the path to it. The docs aren't extremely helpful (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/converter-pdf-files-to-text-format-command/) (https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext)

Is there a way to send the **binary contents** directly into this?

Let's say i'm grabbing a url that directly links to a PDF. I grab the response of that url using python requests,

```
response = requests.get(somePdfUrl)
```

I grab the binary,

```
pdfBinary = response.content
```

And I want to be able to send it into this function and run it using `subprocess` but normally it would be like this:

```
def textExtract(pdfBinary):
    text = subprocess.run(['pdftotext', '/path/to/file.pdf'],
                            stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

This might be impossible and limited to the package but is there way to somehow to insert the pdfBinary into this method? I don't want to have to save the pdf file everytime and then insert it into the subprocess.

Comment: Did you try the usual suspects: use `-` as the file and pipe the content to `stdin`?

Comment: @KlausD. From my understanding `-` outputs to stdout and I can easily show the text extracted from the pdf that way. But I'll be relying on a physical pdf file. What does pipe the content to `stdin` do? `stdin=PIPE`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It's possible:

```
from   subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command = ['pdftotext', '-layout', '-', '-']

p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
r = requests.get(url)

output = p.communicate(input=r.content)[0].decode()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using a modified dockerized version of this utility, say you have a 
Dockerfile:

```
    FROM minidocks/poppler
    CMD cp /dev/stdin myfile.pdf && pdftohtml -noframes -stdout myfile.pdf
```

Build the docker:

```
    $ docker build . -t pdftohtml
```

Then you can do something like

```
    $ cat some-pdf.pdf | docker run -i pdftohtml
```

This can be called from your python script, without the cat of course, you'd feed your binary data to the process.